# Пустой document.cookie в Chrome

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, cookie

Есть код приложенный ниже.  В Firefox как и в IE  при первом обновлении страницы, как и при последующих будет выводится переданная мной строка. А в Chrome у меня постоянно выводится пустая строчка, словно не происходит сохранения в cookie, в настройках Chrome включен пункт "Разрешить сайтам сохранять и читать файлы cookie (рекомендуется)", не могу разобраться в чем причина такой работы у Chrome.
  Прикладываю свой код.

```
alert(document.cookie );

var cookie = "name=" + 444;

document.cookie = cookie;
```

Comment: Уточните, вы запускаете файл локально и в адресной строке у вас адрес на подобие этого `file:///C:/.../siteName.html`, потому что в Chrome возможно отключена поддержка cookie для локальных файлов. Как вариант можно использовать xampp или denver в качестве сервера.

Comment: Да, все верно я запускаю файл локально в адресной строке, причина кроется в том что в  Chrome вшито, что нельзя сохранять cookie?